# Select Range over multiple columns - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

I´m trying to sort columns by value set in a drop down list.
I have got it to work for one column.

Value set in cell: B1
Sort Column A from A5 and hide cells not containing that value.

But I want to be able to sort multiple columns (A, B and C)via value in B1 and hide all rows not containing that specific value. See attatched image. Link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NqC3.png

The working code:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    If Len(Range("B1").Value) > 0 Then Range("A5", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("B1").Value
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Not clear what you really want accomplishing. Do you want sorting or filtering? If filtering, do you want to filter all the columns in discussion simultaneous? Do you want filtering each column at a time, according to specific conditions able to specify the column?

Comment: I just want to be able to filtering all columns at the same time.

Comment: I have different values in column A, B and C  and want to hide/filter all rows that does not contain the data from drop down list in cell B1.

Comment: How does the value of "B1" look?

Comment: You did not answer my clarification question... If you say that the code you show us is working and you need to hide rows which the filtered column values are not equal with something, the value of "B1" should be something like "<>Test"... If yes, please test the code I posted.

Comment: Your code does not work as I intended. If you look at the picture and I choose "A" in the drop down list I want to hide all rows not containing A in any of the coloumns A to C and I still want all rows with A present visible. :)

Comment: Very helpful description, able to help me understand where the problem is... Firstly, can you answer my above question? Then, what does "not work as I intended" mean? I tried reproducing what you say in your question. So, what is happening? Do you receive an error? If yes, what error on which line? If not, what does it do against what you want it doing?

Comment: No error but I get only one row with A when I should have 12.

Comment: I am afraid I did not get the point from your question. If each column is filtered according to the same specific string, everything is hidden if it exists in one of the columns. **This is done by filtering**. The code I posted works (logically) to hide something which you put in "B1" as "<>a". I asked about this aspect, but you did not answer. Everything will remain except "a" in any column. I will delete my answer.

Comment: Please, try the updated code. It filters only the first column, then unhides the lines of the other two columns, according to criteria in "B1". It is a kind of pseudo filtering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim lastR As Long, C As Range, rngDel As Range
  If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        lastR = Me.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
        With Me.Range("A5:C" & lastR)
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
            For Each C In Me.Range("B6:C" & lastR)
                If C.Value = Target.Value Then
                    If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngDel = C
                    Else
                        Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, C)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End With
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

**Edited**:
The following code works when your last workbook structure. Please, try learning and **understanding it**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim lastR As Long, C As Range, rngDel As Range
  If Target.Address = "$E$1" Then
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        lastR = Me.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With Me.Range("G1:J" & lastR)
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
            For Each C In Me.Range("G2:J" & lastR)
                If C.Value = Target.Value Then
                    If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngDel = C
                    Else
                        Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, C)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End With
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

You must use a complete filled column in order to calculate the last filled row!

The above code uses B:B column.

Comment: @David Johansson: Glad I (finally) could help! But in a minute I will post a faster updated code, keeping the range to be unhide in a Union range and unhide at once. Good for big ranges in the processed columns...

Comment: @David Johansson: Please, test/use the updated code.

Comment: Yes it works fine but I cant figure out how to move the cells that I want to filter. Say that I want to filter column G to K instead. What do I need to change. Sorry for this basic questions...

Comment: @David Johansson: What do you mean by "moving the cells that you want to filter"? Did I miss this part of your question? I only could see the part  related to filtering.

Comment: Yes I would like to be able to change the cells myself depending on how the excel sheet turns out. Your code works fine for my initial question but I would like to understand how to change the cells that should be filterd. But I can not understand / get it to work when I try and modify your code to filter for example column G to K.

Comment: @David Johansson:  This is not complicated. You should only change `Me.Range("B6:C" & lastR)` with `Me.Range("G6:K" & lastR)`. You must 'tell' in a way to the application what range you need to process. But you must learn some VBA,  not only copy code. Otherwise, you will not learn anything... If you want filtering A:A and then hide the rows in the columns you mentioned.

Comment: Can not get it to work buy just changing Me.Range("G6:K" & lastR)

Comment: @David Johansson: I told you: It will work if all the other conditions are identic. VBA do not have its own columns preferences... Do you filter the same A:A column?  What does `lastR` return? What does "Can not get it to work" mean? Do you receive an error? If yes, what error and on which code line? If not, what does the code do, against what you wont it to do? Do you use the same "B1" for the filter value? There are  a lot of mistakes which may appear if you change a piece of code without understand how it works.

Comment: I tried to paste the code as an answer but it did not work either. Filter value is E1 so I changed: If Target.Address = "$E$1" Then

Comment: The columns that I want to sort are G5 to J250 so I tried to change Me.Range("G5:J" & lastR)

Comment: Then it just will not work ... but no errors.

Comment: @David Johansson: This is not possible! If you did not change anything and you adapted the new ranges, it should work. I asked you in my previous comment, but for nothing: What value does `lastR` return? Do you know how to check that? For which column does the code calculate it? What type of data do you have in "E1" cell? Is it a string? Did you try your adapted code with similar data as in your above question? Do the events work in your installation?

Comment: Can I email my document to you? No I do not know how to check the lastR value.In cell E1 I have a String "TB30" "TB50" "SI30".

Comment: @David Johansson: If you want sharing the workbook, use [this](https://easyupload.io/) transfer site. It is free and easy to be used. I will look at your workbook and tell you where the problem is.

Comment: If you use the transfer site, do not forget to tag me...

Comment: I will upload the sheet now

Comment: I did not ad the code since the changes I made does not work. I would like cell E1 to be the input value and column G to J ... I can upload what I got ... one sec

Comment: I would think the error is somewhere in: With Me.Range("G3:O" & lastR) and For Each C In Me.Range("G4:O" & lastR)
I have changed these multiple times and cant really figure out how they work :)

Comment: @David Johansson: It looks you do not understand the code at all, even if I asked twice **about the column for which the `lastR` is calculated**. If the `lastR` (last row) is calculated based on A:A column, **where your sheet does not have any record**, of course it will not do anything... Anyhow, I will edit my above code and I will add the working version for your this new case. But do not ask me anything more! You have to learn VBA! These are extremely simple tasks...

Comment: Think I got it ... forgot to change the lastR = Me.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row To "G" in my example

Comment: Why only now, if I asked twice about it and you did not do anything? Then, was it so difficult to adapt the first row, where the filter to put its dorp-down arrows? Have a nice evening!

Comment: Sorry that I did not understand your code, never claimed to understand VBA just trying to learn. Will start with the basics and try to get somewhat basic knowledge in the future. Thanks mate!

Comment: You must try learning by trying! Change as it looks to be logic and see what happens. Come back to the nu modified code and try again in a different direction until you understand each code line what it does. Otherwise, you will never really learn, if you only receive solutions...

Comment: That is true.
Good knowledge in excel/VBA is always useful I guess. 
Anyway thanks again!